# Comparing datatable value to integer in IF statement

Tags: c#, datatable

I am working on a if statement that compare cell values to an integer. The method I used is convert.ToInt16. As result showing below, the if statement becomes very long. I am wondering if there an another approach to shorten the code?

int i, emplyNum;

```
        for (int j = 1; j< 3; j++)
        {
            if ((( Convert.ToInt16(Employee.Rows[j][1]) - 1) < i && i < ( Convert.ToInt16(Employee.Rows[j][2]) + 1)) || ((Convert.ToInt16(Employee.Rows[j][3]) - 1) < i && i < (Convert.ToInt16(Employee.Rows[j][4]) + 1)) || ((Convert.ToInt16(Employee.Rows[j][5]) - 1) < i && i < (Convert.ToInt16(Employee.Rows[j][6]) + 1)))
            {
                emplyNum = j;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes it's totally possible to shorten most of it by refactoring out repetetive code using well known patterns, like the rule engine pattern. The questing is: is it worth it for you? After all, you will end up with way more code, then you began with. You could also evaluate, if you can switch from a datatable to a strongly typed collection like `List<T>`, that would remove the `Convert.ToInt16()` calls.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have looked up  List<T>. As you mention, it will end up with more code. I will stick with original code.